# How to remove this lines in the middle?

Tags: regex, jvm, jstack

I have dump JVM thread from a server. From the dump, I'd like to erase some line using regex.

```
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x00000005b8052b20> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"catalina-exec-126" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f7b58ac5800 nid=0x4171 runnable [0x00007f7ac4800000]
```

I want the output to be like this

```
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"catalina-exec-126" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f7b58ac5800 nid=0x4171 runnable [0x00007f7ac4800000]
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this using regex? Because the value is dynamic. Please suggest

Comment: Well, for starters, what have you tried? Also, what is and is not static content? What is dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you made a thread dump.

You can try this awk one-liner to modify your dump file:

```
awk -v RS="\n\n" -v ORS="\n\n" '!/Locked ownable synchro/' yourDump > newDump
```

btw, this is not a java question, although your input file was created by jstack.

Comment: Thanks. This is an elegant solution I think